# Fill numbers from 1 to n,fast algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need algorithm what can fill string/array/etc by numbers from 1 to n; 1 <= 1 <= 10^8.
Time limit ≈ 2 seconds.

```
n = 100000000;
arr = [];
for (let i = 1;i <= n;i++){
    arr.push(i)
}
console.log(arr)
```

If try like this it takes 33.785 seconds that too much

Comment: Do you know about `for` loops (in most languages)? In any case describe REAL problem and show own efforts.

Comment: If i use 'for' it will take a very long time

Comment: Show us the code. And problem definition (I doubt that task is " fill string/array/etc by numbers from 1 to n")

Comment: There is no task as such, just interesting how can i do that as fast as possible.If i'll write like this (in js):

`function fill(n){
    let temp = '';
    for(let i = 1;i <= n;i++){
        temp+=String(i);
    }
    return temp;
}`

Comment: You definitely need a language tag on this question. And you definitely want an array, not a string.

Comment: @user3386109 anyway i write it like example,if fill array it will be as long as with string;language too,i need just algorithm

Comment: @nqx1 The algorithm you have implemented in your example is optimal. Filling *O(n)* array elements takes *O(n)* time. Everything else is down to the capabilities of specific languages.

Comment: Something to try: preallocate the array with `arr = new Array(n)`, and use `arr[i-1] = i` to set the entries.

Comment: btw: If you include the `console.log(arr)` in the time, then yes, it will take a lot of time no matter how you fill the array.

Comment: @beaker: but do note that for instance in JavaScript (this tag was added after the question was asked), large number of sequential pushes are going to be slower than other techniques that pre-allocate an array, because of the array copying required as the array grows with `push`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Nothing I have said contradicts your comment, so far as I know. The algorithm is optimal. Run-time of the implementation of that algorithm can no doubt be improved, but the details of that implementation are necessarily language-dependent.

Comment: @beaker: I think the point is that if you're talking `big-O` optimal, you're right, or close to it.  But in JS, `Array .from ({length: 1e8}, (_, i) => i + 1)` will probably take a third the time of the OPs code, and you can probably get another factor of two if you replace that callback with a `for`-loop.  So the coefficients matter!

Comment: @ScottSauyet You're not wrong. My entire point was to get the OP to understand that the implementation language *is important* to getting them a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You make multiple reallocation of memory for string - this is rather long procedure.

If possible - preset list/array capacity, then fill it with values, rather than increment length one-by-one. In Python you can use list comprehension - perhaps JS has something alike.

For strings use a kind of StringBuilder if available.